# Weka arff file cannot open using weka software

Tags: weka, arff

I am trying to open the following arff file using weak software but it gives me an error.

The error says:- Unable to determine structure as arff(Reasoon:java.io.IOExcaption: Problem reading attribute weight for input string:"Contravene", read Tolen[Contravene],line 20)

```
@relation ParkingFines

@attribute OffenceDate DATE "D/M/YY"
@attribute OffenceType string {Contravene No Stopping Sign,Fail to Obey Instruction-No Valid Ticket Correctly Displayed,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired}
@attribute ExpiationAmount {91,50}
@attribute StatusClass {Paid,Exemption,Transferred to FERU}

@data
1/5/17,Contravene No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
1/5/17,Contravene No Stopping Sign,91,Exemption
1/5/17,Contravene No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
1/5/17,Contravene No Stopping Sign,91,Transferred to FERU
1/5/17,Fail to Obey Instruction-No Valid Ticket Correctly Displayed,50,Paid
1/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Exemption
1/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Paid
2/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
2/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Exemption
2/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
2/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Transferred to FERU
2/5/17,Fail to Obey Instruction-No Valid Ticket Correctly Displayed,50,Paid
2/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Exemption
2/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Paid
3/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
3/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Exemption
3/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Paid
3/5/17,Contravene-No Stopping Sign,91,Transferred to FERU
3/5/17,Fail to Obey Instruction-No Valid Ticket Correctly Displayed,50,Paid
3/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Exemption
3/5/17,Fail to pay parking fee-Ticket Expired,50,Paid
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/RE-weka-load-error-unable-to-determine-structure-as-arff-reason-java-ioexception-keyword-relation-ex-td26310.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the csv file with the required headers only as this error may cause due to the extra rows that are neither headers nor data rows and this is a university home work. so try some work around to solve the issue. finally place headers for specific rows and remove other content  from the file.